# How to execute a request at a specific time every day?

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-service, android-room, android-database

Let's assume that I am developing an application that allows me to monitor the psychological state of a person every day. When a user completes another survey, the data for the day is saved to the database.
But if the user has not completed the survey during the day, the result Day(0, 0, 0) should be sent to the database

The question is How to implement a behavior so that at a certain time (11:59 pm) the application checks whether something is in the database for that day or not? What should i use to implement this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! how are you? please see the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857101/schedule-task-in-android  i think is what you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Work Manager** to do periodic work.

check out this approved answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330829/7209822